# NSView in NSScrollview. Problems with document view scrolling

Tags: nsview, nsscrollview

I have a NSView subclass ImageTransform where I perform image zooming by using Core Image filter CILanczosScaleTransform. Image then is drawn to the surface. All ok till this point.
I would like to embed the NSView subclass (ImageTransform) into NSScrollView so that it performs scrolling when the view object gets bigger than Window's content size.

For this reason I implement the scroll view with the following code:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    ImageTransform *imageTransform = [[ImageTransform alloc]init];
    [imageTransform doZooming];
    [self.window setContentSize:NSMakeSize(800, 600)];


    //Get width and height of the image after zooming and set the ImageTransform     instance bounds to match output image dimensions.
    float height = imageTransform.imgOutHeight;
    float width = imageTransform.imgOutWidth;
    [imageTransform setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height)];

    //Set up a scroll view
    self.scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:[[self.window contentView]frame]];
    [self.scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
    [self.scrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:YES];
    [self.scrollView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
    [self.scrollView setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
    [self.scrollView setDocumentView:imageTransform];
    [self.window setContentView:self.scrollView];
    NSLog(@"NSView width %f height %f", imageTransform.bounds.size.width, imageTransform.bounds.size.height);

}
@end
```

However, **the problem is that the ScrollViewer's document** view (which is an instance of ImageTransform class and which is bigger than self.window's contentView) **fills into the contentView**. The image moves around when I move the mouse, but as it moves it gets distorted and blurred. Setting up scroll view went fine when I created an NSImageView object and passed it to scrollview as a parameter, but in my case I have to use imageTransform as a document view.

I know this is a novice question and I apologise (because I am novice here :). Setting up scrollview is supposed to be easy but I have tried everything and no luck so far.

I am adding the ImageTransform class code too (this is where image resizing and drawing goes on):

```
-(CIImage*)doZooming
{

    NSURL *imageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"the-shining-axe" withExtension:@"jpg"];
    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    self.transformFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILanczosScaleTransform"];
    [self.transformFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] forKey:@"inputScale"];
    [self.transformFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputAspectRatio"];
    [self.transformFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    self.outputImage = [self.transformFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    self.outputImageExtent = self.outputImage.extent;
    self.imgOutHeight = self.outputImageExtent.size.height;
    self.imgOutWidth = self.outputImageExtent.size.width;
    return self.outputImage;
}


- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    //[super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    self.cIContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] CIContext];

    [self.cIContext drawImage:[self doZooming] inRect:dirtyRect fromRect:self.outputImage.extent];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by changing the following line of code:

```c
[self.cIContext drawImage:[self doZooming]
                   inRect:dirtyRect
                 fromRect:self.outputImage.extent];
```

to this:

```c
[self.cIContext drawImage:[self doZooming]
                   inRect:self.outputImage.extent
                 fromRect:self.outputImage.extent];
```